# Xamarin - Set Up Azure Offline Sync in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, azure, xamarin

I have watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsKjJ6ohjSA&t=1942s) tutorial on setting up offline sync for a Xamarin application using an Azure backend. I have a MySQL table on my Azure portal and I now wish to add the back-end calls to sync my local SQLite database with the MySQL cloud database.

I am not using the Easy Tables software used in the tutorial above, and I would like to use C# for the backend calls for my `MobileServiceClient` to talk to, where it calls methods such as:

- `await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();`
- `await table.PullAsync("alltable", table.CreateQuery());`
- `await table.InsertAsync(entry);`

What are the steps to setting up the cloud syncing functionality from my SQLite store to my MySQL database?

Comment: It seems that Mysql  Offline sync is not supported currently. Base on my knowledge, it is done by Azure SDK. if you have any idea about azure mobile service, we could give our [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to the azure team.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set up MySQL back-end in Azure for Xamarin Offline Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299143/set-up-mysql-back-end-in-azure-for-xamarin-offline-sync)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL is not compatible with Azure's `IMobileServiceClient`, you must change to using Azure SQL to use the inbuilt functions in `IMobileServiceClient`