# Set up MySQL back-end in Azure for Xamarin Offline Sync

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, azure

I have a `MySQL` database set up through the `Azure Portal`, currently hosted on `ClearDB`. I have created a mobile app using `Xamarin Forms` that implements an `SQLite` database which stores relevant information for my app in it. I am implementing offline sync functionality using the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore` library, and I am using functions such as:

- `await table.ToListAsync();`
- `await table.UpdateAsync(entry);`
- `await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();`
- `await table.PullAsync("allEntry", table.CreateQuery());`

The last thing I need to do is sync my local SQLite database with the `Azure` cloud `MySQL` database I have created. How do I implement this in C# (or Node.js .. or ANY language) such that my SQLite database can sync entries with my Azure MySQL database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, I tried to create my **Azure Mobile App** project via Visual Studio, and install [MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity) which supports MySQL for EF6, then create my table controller working with my DBContext for MySQL.

I created my db model that inherits the [EntityData](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Entity/EntityData.cs) which contains the table column type `DateTimeOffset`, but I encountered a incompatible error message. Then I found there is a known bug in MySQL Connector as follows:

> An Entity Framework DbContext object created with a column of type **DateTimeOffset** returned an error indicating that DateTimeOffset values were incompatible with **DateTime** and **Timestamp** values. (Bug #24732001)

I found a [release note](http://insidemysql.com/mysql-connectornet-7-0-6-m5-development-has-been-released/) about MySQL Connector/NET, then I tried to upgrade to [MySql.Data.Entity 7.0.7-m61](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/7.0.7-m61), but another problem about [TypeLoadException - MySqlEFConfiguration](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,652115,652115#msg-652115) encountered.

Since your goal is to use offline sync for your Xamarin app with azure mobile app, I recommend that you could try to use sql database or azure table storage for your data storage instead of MySQL, which could build your mobile app backend in a simple way. You could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started) for getting started with it.

Comment: Thank you Bruce, unfortunately our database uses MySQL and were aren't able to change to an SQL database or azure table storage at this time

Comment: Any concerns when using azure SQL with mobile app, feel free to let us know.